# How to add post ID to JSON URL?

Tags: json, wordpress

I am not familiar with PHP Syntax. Now i added JSON Plugin to my wordpress website and activate it.

When i open url to `get_recent_post` , it's fine. JSON data are showing.

But when i open `get_post` , it's only showing

```
{"status":"error","error":"Include 'id' or 'slug' var in your request."}
```

So i don't know how to add post id to that URL.

here is the pic. Another `get_page , gate_date_posts`, etc... links are same showing error.

[image]

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2):

To display a post's ID, simply use the following PHP code within the WordPress loop:

```
<?php the_ID(); ?>
```

To return the ID, use the following PHP code within the WordPress loop:

```
<?php get_the_ID; ?>
```

To get a post's id outside of the WordPress loop use the following PHP code:

```
<?php global $post; $post->ID ?>
```

Hope that helps you.

Answer (score -2):

http://yoursite.com/api/get_posts/

with the s

If you use the WordPress link and click on it, you will be fine.