# post ID to JSON

Tags: ng-show

When i open url to get_recent_post , it's fine. JSON data are showing.

But when i open get_post , it's only showing

{"status":"error","error":"Include 'id' or 'slug' var in your request."}

I DO not undrestand in under post
[How to add post ID to JSON URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599500/how-to-add-post-id-to-json-url)

please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add post ID to JSON URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599500/how-to-add-post-id-to-json-url)

Comment: My site has a problem when:
Get_Post . display mesaage {"status":"error","error":"Include 'id' or 'slug' var in your request."}